# MySQL error, "You have an error in your SQL syntax"

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I always get problem or error like this:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near `'kunci=1 WHERE date='2013-09-01' AND user_id='2'' at line 1

Here is my php coding:

```
if(isset($_POST['mc'])) {

    $mcdate = $_POST['mcdate'];
    $mcstaff = $_POST['mcstaff'];

    $sql = mysql_query("
        SELECT * 
        FROM timetable 
        WHERE 
            date ='" . $mcdate . "' 
            AND shift='O' 
            AND user_id='" . $mcstaff . "'");

    $counto = mysql_num_rows($sql);
    echo $counto;

    if ($counto == 0) {

        $sql1 = "
            UPDATE timetable 
            SET 
                shift='A' 
                kunci=1 
            WHERE 
                date='" . $mcdate . "' 
                AND user_id='" . $mcstaff . "'";
        mysql_query($sql1) or die(mysql_error());

        $sql2 = mysql_query("
            SELECT * 
            FROM timetable 
            WHERE date ='" . $mcdate . "' 
            AND shift='M'");
        $countm=mysql_num_rows($sql2);          
        //echo $countm;

        $sql3 = mysql_query("
            SELECT * 
            FROM timetable 
            WHERE 
                date ='" . $mcdate . "' 
                AND shift='E'");                    
        $counte=mysql_num_rows($sql3);
        //echo $counte;

        //balance shift
        if($counte==$countm) {

            $rand=rand(0, 2);
            if($rand==0) {
                $shift = 'M';
            } else {
                $shift = 'E';
            }

        } else if ($countm>$counte) {

            $shift = 'E';

        } else if ($counte>$countm) {

            $shift = 'M';

        }

    } else if ($counto == 1) {

        echo "Staff already Off";

    }
}
```

I also have try enclose database, table and column names in backticks to prevent such conflicts but it still come out with this error.

I also realized that in my MySQL table for timetable got collation for 'shift' structure. I don't know if it can effect.

My table = timetable:

```
name: shift, type:varchar(10), collation:latin1_swedish_ci.
```

Can somebody help me? Thanks you so much.

Comment: You must comma-separate column=value pairs in the `SET` clause.  `SET shift='A', kunci=1`

Comment: Note that this is vulnerable to SQL injection.  The `mysql_*()` API is deprecated - focus your efforts on learning to use an API supporting parametized queries, such as PDO or MySQLi.

Comment: ok got it. thanks you so much. i just learn php. :)

Comment: @cocotyer: you may wish to copy of the improved formatting back to your codebase - having ~100 character margins is (imo) very helpful to making code easier to work with. It helps if you use editors side-by-side too.

Comment: @halfer Great point! :) You know, I did came across the bug and stopped a second to ensure that the bug was not fixed accidentally.

Comment: @halfer thanks you so much for your helping. so sorry i'm new here. not knowing so much the formatting. :) i will take noted that.

Answer (score 5):

```
$sql1=("UPDATE timetable SET shift='A' kunci=1 WHERE date='".$mcdate."' AND user_id='".$mcstaff."'");
```

should be

```
$sql1=("UPDATE timetable SET shift='A', kunci=1 WHERE date='".$mcdate."' AND user_id='".$mcstaff."'");
                                      ^------  missing comma
```

Comment: Thanks u so much. my bad after 1 day not sleep. thanks again

Comment: @cocotyer: don't forget to tick this, to mark this question as fixed. Thanks!

Comment: @halfer how to tick? sorry i just new in here.

Comment: @cocotyer: there should be a green "tick" or "check mark" (✓) to the left of this answer. Click it to accept; it gives the answerer a few "reputation points" too, so is a good way of expressing appreciation.